# Google Maps API Heatmap Layer - Single gradient, Two extremes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

Say I have a google heatmap layer set up in the usual way:

```
  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    radius: 20,
    opacity: 0.5,
    gradient: g
  });

  heatmap.setMap(map);
```

where:

```
  var g = [
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7)',
    'rgba(173, 255, 47, 0.5)',
    'rgba(152, 251, 152, 0)',
    'rgba(152, 251, 152, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 238, 0.5)',
    'rgba(186, 85, 211, 0.7)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'

]
```

The thing I am heatmapping take a range of 0 to 1. I would like to show a hotspot for values close to 0 and close to 1 and neutral (cool) spots close to 0.5. That is why I have higher opacities closer to the beginning and end of that `g` variable.

The problem is that the heatmap layer interprets NO data as 0 and therefore heatmaps empty areas of the map to red. What I want is *data* near 0 and 1 to be red and areas of no data to be left alone.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You should set the first gradient to no (or little) opacity.

```
var g = [
'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.9)',
'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.7)',
'rgba(173, 255, 47, 0.5)',
'rgba(152, 251, 152, 0)',
'rgba(152, 251, 152, 0)',
'rgba(0, 0, 238, 0.5)',
'rgba(186, 85, 211, 0.7)',
'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9)',
'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)']
```

Comment: Probably not the thing OP was looking for. I'm in this dilemma too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tinker with the data before drawing it?

```
if (num > 0.5)
    num = 1 - num
```

Now numbers near 0 will be the same as those near 1 and a regular gradient can be used.